# C# & SQL Server CE : treat words after defined symbols (+ or &) as a seperate word in search

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I'm working on a simple translation application based on C# & SQL Server CE 3.5

I have a search textbox that searches certain columns in database through `textBox1.Text` with normal SQL query [`SELECT.. LIKE '% %'`]

---

*What I want to achieve :*
**I want to search for all the words after certain symbols (+ for example) in all locations in database , so they don't need to be written in the full context** (word after word as they exist in database)

*In other words :*
**I want to split words after certain symbols , so that the program search for each word independently** (search the word before symbol and each word after symbol separately)

---

***Example:***
If I tried to search for the value "burden of proof" , I've to write it in the previous context, but for the user this will not apply. So I want him to put a symbol in-between the two words he is willing to search for (namely he should search for "burden+proof")

Picture 1 : https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBJTV.jpg , Picture 2 : https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYl0w.jpg

---

Edit - my search button code :

```
sqlcmd = new SqlCeCommand
                ("SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE EnglishWord like '%" + textBox1.Text + "%' OR EnglishDesc like '%" + textBox1.Text + "%' OR ArabicWord like '%" + textBox1.Text + "%' OR ArabicDesc like '%" + textBox1.Text + "%' ", sqlcon);

            try
            {
                listView1.Items.Clear();
                sqldr = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (sqldr.Read())
                {

                    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(sqldr["ID"].ToString());
                    item.SubItems.Add(sqldr["EnglishWord"].ToString());
                    item.SubItems.Add(sqldr["EnglishDesc"].ToString());
                    item.SubItems.Add(sqldr["ArabicDesc"].ToString());
                    item.SubItems.Add(sqldr["ArabicWord"].ToString());
                    item.SubItems.Add(sqldr["Subject"].ToString());

                    listView1.Items.Add(item);
                }
                listView1.Enabled = true;
                label7.Text = listView1.Items.Count.ToString();
            }
            catch (SqlCeException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message, "Something wrong");
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer by : **Richard Deeming** @ *[CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Answers/894493/Split-words-after-predefined-symbol-into-more-than)*

---

Assuming you want to find all records where each word appears in at least one of the four columns, something like this should work:

```
sqlcmd = sqlcon.CreateCommand();

string[] words = textBox1.Text.Split(new[] { '+' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder("SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE 1 = 1");

for (int index = 0; index < words.Length; index++)
{
    string wordToFind = words[index];
    string parameterName = "@word" + index;
    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameterName, "%" + wordToFind + "%");
    query.AppendFormat(" AND (EnglishWord Like {0} OR EnglishDesc Like {0} OR ArabicWord Like {0} OR ArabicDesc Like {0})", parameterName);
}

sqlcmd.CommandText = query.ToString();
```

This will also fix the SQL Injection[^] vulnerability in your code.

If the user searches for burden+proof, the resulting query will look something like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    T1
WHERE
    1 = 1
And
    (
        EnglishWord Like @word0 
    Or 
        EnglishDesc Like @word0 
    Or 
        ArabicWord Like @word0 
    Or 
        ArabicDesc Like @word0
    )
And
    (
        EnglishWord Like @word1 
    Or 
        EnglishDesc Like @word1 
    Or 
        ArabicWord Like @word1 
    Or 
        ArabicDesc Like @word1
    )

/*
Parameters:
- @word0 = '%burden%'
- @word1 = '%proof%'
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So you got different words from the answer here.
[Split textbox.text into other textboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29441449/split-textbox-text-into-other-textboxes/29441481#29441481)

You have this `string[] result` that you know if the length is 1 than it didnt split at all. If it is more than 1 than the original text was split with + or whatever.

I am not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve but you could do this.

```
if(result.Length == 1)
{
   //Select * from database where column = result[0]
}
else
{
  foreach(string s in result)
  {
   //Select * from database where column like '%'+s+'%' (better if you do with parameters)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your interest again , but forgive me for my complete ignorance. I'll try to rephrase my question with an example. **If I've a record in the database have the value "C# is good" and I try to search for it with "C# good" it will show nothing ,right ?** What I try to achieve is to split search command after a predefined symbol (+ in our case) , so when I try to search for "C# + good" it will try to find "C#" and "good" in the same record with no need for the two words to be followed by each other. It would be great if you could modify the code I've provided please. Thanks in advance

Comment: yes if you search for C# good it will not show because you dont have + or something. but if you search for C#+good than it will show what you want. the code will enter in the first if statement if you search for C# good and it will enter the else part if you search for C#+good. does that make sense

Comment: yes sir I think you get my point now , the problem is that I don't know how to apply that to my code using your methods mentioned here and in the other question.

Comment: Edit : I've rephrased the whole question , provided pictures. I'm really desperate to get this function working and grateful for your help , thanks.