# Split textbox.text into other textboxes

Tags: c#

The result that I'm seeking at the moment is to split textBox1.Text into as many textboxes as possible , as long as the splitting sign exist **('+' or '#' for example)**

So each new textbox should only have the word between the two signs
example :

> textBox1.text = "one+two+three"; then textBox2.text = "one";
>   textBox3.text = "two"; textBox3.text = "three";

The following two examples achieve 90% of what I need , but I still can't figure out how to put the values each in a separate textBox.text :

```
string str = "one\n   \ntwo\n   \nthree\n   \n   \nfour";
string[] result = Regex.Split(str, "\n\\s*");
for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
    MessageBox.Show(result[i]);
```

and

```
string input = "one)(two)(three)(four)(five";
string[] result = input.Split(new string[] { ")(" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
foreach (string s in result)
    MessageBox.Show(s);
```

Comment: Is this a windows app (WPF or WinForms) or a web app (MVC or WebForms)?

Comment: @epotter it's Windows app (WinForms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to split the result (as you already did) and then for each result dynamically create a textbox and set its text. Your code should look like this:

```
int i = 0;
foreach (var item in result)
{
    var textBox = new TextBox();
    textBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0,i++*25);
    textBox.Text = item;
    this.Controls.Add(textBox);
}
```

The integer i is used to make sure that each textbox appears at a different location and not on top of each other.

Comment: Well that was what I'm actually looking for , much appreciated , but could I go more further ?
I'd like to know how to use the text values in the split textboxes as a new search term . So "Burden+of+proof" should be split to 3 search terms rather than one.
I'm using SQL server CE and C# WinForms .. Thanks for your time
For more explanation , kindly check my other unanswered question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29409857/c-sharp-sql-server-ce-treat-words-after-defined-symbols-or-as-a-sepera

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
string[] result = textBox1.text.Split('+');

foreach (int i=0;i<result.Lenght;i++)
{
TextBox box = new TextBox();
box.Name = "textBox"+i;
box.Text = result[i];
somewhere.Add(box);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time , but I couldn't get your code to work , forgive me but I'm totally a newbie . Also it has some typos like (textBox1.**T**ext) and (Leng**th**).

Comment: well i didnt mean it to be the exact code. just tried to push you to the answer. but i guess you got it from the other answer.